# Why, when I sort a list of 13 numbers, does python only return the last number?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of first name, last name, and score in a text file that refers to a student and their test score. When I go to sort them so I can find the median score, it only returns from the sort() the last grade on the list. I need it to return all of them, but obviously sorted in order. Here is the part of my code in question:

```
def main():
    #open file in read mode
    gradeFile = open("grades.txt","r")
    #read the column names and assign them to line1 variable
    line1 = gradeFile.readline()
    #tell it to look at lines 2 to the end
    lines = gradeFile.readlines()
    #seperate the list of lines into seperate lines
    for line in lines:
        #initialize grades list as an empty list
        gradeList = []
        #iterate through each line and take off the \n
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.split(",")
        grades = line[-1]
        try:
            gradeList.append(float(grades))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        #print(gradeList)
    #sort the grades
    gradeList.sort(reverse=False)
    print(gradeList)
```

Comment: You are resseting `gradeList`  to an empty array at every loop. You need to put that line `gradeList = []` outside the `for`

Comment: Oh okay, I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You clear the list each time the loop runs. Move the assignment outside the loop.

Comment: This really should be a comment, but it does solve the problem. I've never been this conflicted about upvoting!